# Client Object Model call context.executeQueryAsync: After adding an item to a list, cant open the new item until the onQuerySucceeded completes?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have client side javascript code that successfully adds items to a list.  I now want to open the new item after I create it, via that same script, but the new item does not open until I allow the onQuerySucceeded script called by the executeQueryAsync  context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded , onQueryFail);  ﻿﻿ has been allowed to run.

The new item will not open from the SP List or code until the onQuerySucceeded  completes.  It appears the item is locked.  Soon after the call is allowed to complete, the item can be opened via any method.

Do I need to call context.dispose() or is there some other way to commit the row and release any sp locks?

```
// 
newItem.update();

context.load(newItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded , onQueryFail);

SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(nid);
nid ='';

 function onQuerySucceeded (sender, args) {
    var lnewItem_ID = newItem.get_id();
    gNewItemId=lnewItem_ID;

    nid ='';

    if (gOpenNewItemDialog == "true" && gNewItemId != "" )
    {
        try
        {
         var linktopopup ="https://my.site.com/teams/abc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId={A88775A1-18F4-482C-A5AC-6F44C5B1CF03}&ID=" + gNewItemId;
                          // this call hangs.  Also, item shows in sp list but cant be opened.
            OpenPopup(linktopopup, "Edit new matter Task");

        }
        catch(err)
        {

            alert(' :( ');
        }
        gOpenNewItemDialog=false; //reset
    }           
}

function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to add new item. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:  The Edit Task dialog now opens the item as expected.  I am not sure why.  I *may* have changed a list setting related to email notifications on change of assignment.

HTH

/bac